# Can not Deserialize json string to class

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a class library project in .net. I can't use 3rd party assemblies, only Microsoft assemblies allowed.

I have a return class from web API like below. I try to Deserialize string to this class and it's not working but it works for other classes. I think the problem is the 'T' class accepting.

my class;

```
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public bool HasError { get; set; }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public string DetailedErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

    public ApiResponse(string errorCode, string errorMessage, string detailedErrorMessage = "")
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.ErrorCode = errorCode;
        this.HasError = true;
        this.DetailedErrorMessage = detailedErrorMessage;
    }

    public ApiResponse(T value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.HasError = false;
        ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
    }

    public ApiResponse()
    {
        this.HasError = false;
        ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
    }

    public ApiResponse(OLException e)
    {
        ErrorCode = e.ErrorCode;
        ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        HasError = true;
        DetailedErrorMessage = e.StackTrace;
    }

    public ApiResponse(Exception e)
    {
        ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        HasError = true;
        DetailedErrorMessage = e.StackTrace;
    }
}
```

and here is my Deserialize function.

```
private T JsonDeserialize<T>(string jsonString)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
    T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
    return obj;
}
```

and here is the How I use the following method

```
ApiResponse<bool> response = JsonDeserialize<ApiResponse<bool>>(responseString);
```

Response string -->

> {"value":false,"hasError":true,"errorMessage":"user1 client already
>   exists.","detailedErrorMessage":"","errorCode":null}

There is no error just response class seems null after deserialize but as you see, the response string has some values.

[image]

Comment: What's the error? what's the json like? and what type T are you using for JsonDeserialize?

Comment: edit the question with additional information. please check again.

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or .NET FW?

Comment: I'm using .net core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already referenced `System.Text.Json` (Microsoft), so you can just do this:

```
static T DeserializeEasyWay<T>(string input)
{
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(input, 
        new JsonSerializerOptions{PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true});
}
```

I tested with your string. It works.

Comment: I'd suggest using the Name property of the DataMemberAttribute instead. It's possible to have both a "value", "Value" and "vAlUe" property in the json.

Answer (score 2):

The `DataContractJsonSerializer` is a case sensitive, then it consider the property `value` and `Value` are different.

To resolve the issue, you could change the class `ApiResponse`to:

```
[DataContract]
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public T Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "hasError")]
    public bool HasError { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "errorMessage")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "detailedErrorMessage")]
    public string DetailedErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "errorCode")]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

    // add other method ...
}
```

I hope this helps you fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting .NET Core 3.x, you may use `System.Text.Json` API with case insensitive properties names

```cs
var properties = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
var response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ApiResponse<bool>>(jsonString, properties);
```

It's also possible to get it through Nuget for .NET Core 2.x or .NET Framework 4.7.2 or 4.8.

For old .NET Framework you can use built-in [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
var response = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ApiResponse<bool>>(jsonString);
```

In this case you'll need to add `System.Web.Extensions.dll` to the project references and `System.Web.Script.Serialization` to using directives

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the annotations for the DataContractJsonSerializer.

```cs
[DataContract]
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public T Value { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool HasError { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DetailedErrorMessage { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

.... etc...
```

Comment: I try before but It didn't help. I found the problem, the problem is case sensitivity but I don't know is there a setting for case sensitivity in DataContractJsonSerializer. Because I can't use any 3rd part assembly like Newtonsoft.

Comment: I don't believe there is an option in DataContractJsonSerializer for case insensitivity. I think in this case you'd have to modify your application to handle this either with middleware, or if it's a desktop application, with a class to change this before attempting to deserialise the data.